# Writing a simple CMakeLists.txt file for ROS

Tags: roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS (Indigo), and I want to write a C++ program to use the MoveIt! package.

However, I am confused as to what I need to have in my CMakeLists.txt file, such that the header and library files can be found.

For example, here is the file so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

project(MicoMoveIt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

file(GLOB srcs *.cpp)

include_directories(/opt/ros/indigo/include)

link_directories(/opt/ros/indigo/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${srcs})
```

And my main.cpp file is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>

int main()
{
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("right_arm");
    return 0;
}
```

But compiling this gives me the error:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/robot_model/joint_model.h:47: error: Eigen/Geometry: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Geometry>
                          ^
```

So, I need to specify where to find these Eigen header files. But given that Eigen is a dependency of MoveIt!, then I shouldn't have to manually include all these header file directories.

How should I be writing the CMakeLists.txt file so that all header and library directories of dependencies are included?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209887/writing-a-simple-cmakelists.txt-file-for-ros/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-05-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-14**:
Did you review [the extensive documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) on `CMakeLists.txt` and catkin and the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For what it's worth,

Could you try to install these packages:

ros-indigo-eigen-utils, ros-indigo-eigen-conversions

I'm using currently groovy and I don't have any experiences with indigo, but did you follow this tutorial ?

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I would suggest you to follow all the tutorials for the beginner before writing any code.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Fleurmond](https://answers.ros.org/users/22507/fleurmond/) with karma: 46 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is not really related to the problem, but here's my answer to your actual problem with Eigen specifically. It's an issue with Ubuntu 14.04's installation of Eigen3 which I guess must have changed since the Moveit code was written. You can fix this by creating a symlink from `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen` to `/usr/local/include/Eigen` and CMake should be able to find the libraries. Of course, double-check that those libraries really do exist in that path.

---

Originally posted by [crunchex](https://answers.ros.org/users/25178/crunchex/) with karma: 376 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1